# Getting Count of Rows With Join in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

What is the correct way to get a count of rows whose specified column is a foreign key of another table. Here's what I mean:

I have 2 tables `providers` and `products`. The providers table has primary key `provider_id`and the table `products` has a foreign key reference to `provider_id` via a column named the same, `provider_id`. My intention is to fetch the details of each provider including all their products, that is a total of all instances where `provider_id` in the `products` table matched `providers_id` in the `providers` table.

Here's my code:

```
$data = DB::table('providers')
            ->join('products', 'products.provider_id', '=', 'providers.provider_id')
            ->select(
                'providers.provider_id AS id',
                'providers.provider_name AS name',
                DB::raw("count(products->where('products.provider_id','=','providers.provider_id')) AS total_products"),
                'providers.claims AS claims',
                'providers.settlements AS settlements')
        ->groupBy('provider')
        ->get();
```

This seems not to work as I am getting the error below:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$id (View: /var/www/test/app/resources/views/agent/serviceproviders/index.blade.php)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Oluwafemi Sule.

Comment: probably a conflict with products.id and why do you even give aliases as you dont use them anywhere ?

Comment: @AnarBayramov there's no products.id. The common aspect between the two tables is the primary key in the providers table which is providers.provider_id (yes, I named the column provider_id which also auto increments instead of the normal id people often use). I found the issue and sorted it, I'm about to post the correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in how I was counting the rows and how I was grouping the data for proper counting. I feel so dumb, this was too easy. Below is the correct code:

```
$data = DB::table('providers')
            ->join('products', 'products.provider_id', '=', 'providers.provider_id')
            ->select(
                'providers.provider_id AS id',
                'providers.provider_name AS name',
                DB::raw("count(products.provider_id) AS total_products"))
        ->groupBy('providers.provider_id')
        ->get();
```